# Display all categories a product belong to on product page

Tags: magento-1.9, phtml

I need to display all categories from one product on product view page.

This code I found, but it displays one category per line:

```
<?php $categories = $_product->getCategoryIds(); ?>
<?php foreach($categories as $k => $_category_id): ?>
<?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category_id) ?> 
< <a href="<?php echo $_category->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName() ?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But I need it this way:
cat 1
cat 2 > subcat 1
cat 3 > subcat 1 > subcat 2

Comment: This may help you https://makandracards.com/vasan/28099-getting-magento-category-paths-for-a-specific-product

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```
<?php 
$categories = $_product->getCategoryIds();
if (count($categories) > 0){
    foreach($categories as $k => $_category_id){
        $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category_id);
        echo $_category->getName();
        echo $_category->getId();
        $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories();
        if (count($_subcategories) > 0){      
            foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory){
                 echo $_subcategory->getName();
                 echo $_subcategory->getId();
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```